# Splitting a string to remove everything before the last dot and remove the underscore at the end of a string?

Tags: r

I am trying to split a string `S1.S2.S3.S4.Success_` with the use of a regex expression to just get the `Success` part. I plan on getting the Success part by getting the 5th group of non-punctuation characters. So I need a regex expression that removes everything before the last dot and removes the last underscore in the above string.

I believe I have it working for another string in the format of `S1_S2_S3`: `_\\s*(?=[^_]+$)` which gets me the `S3` part of this string. But I cannot seem to get it working for the `S1.S2.S3.S4.Success_` string.

**Update:**

This code is working...

```
x <- "S1.S2.S3.S4.Success_"
sapply(strsplit(x, ".", fixed = TRUE), function(x) tail(x, 2)[2])
[1] "Success_"
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "_"))
```

Comment: If you have working regex to match the part you want, `stringr::str_extract` works nicely. If not, you'll need to be much more specific.

Comment: @Gregor I have updated the question.

Comment: Okay, so then we need to know how you plan to identify the `Success` part for extraction. Are you looking for the first consecutive set of multiple letters? The 13th-19th characters? The 5th group on non-punctuation characters? The last set of non-punctuation characters? Something else? A few more examples of strings you want the code to work on, as well as your expected results, and a explanation of the unifying logic for the different examples, would help us understand your problem.

Comment: As for why your regex doesn't match Success in this example, `[^_]+` matches non-underscore characters, and `$` matches the end of the string. Putting it together, `[^_]+$` matches non-underscore characters at the end of the string. You sample string ends with an underscore, so no match.

Comment: @Gregor check out my edit :)

Comment: @Gregor I got it working and have edited the question as result of this. Thanks so much for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description "get the 5th group of non-punctuation characters", I would suggest this. It splits the string by all punctuation characters, and then extracts the 5th element.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "[[:punct:]]"), "[", 5)
[1] "Success"
```

If you instead want the last group of non-punctuation characters, use `sapply(strsplit(x, "[[:punct:]]"), tail, 1)`.